# Strange Behavior of the string array in JavaScript on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

Try Following Code in IE 11.

```
var d= new Date();
var lt=d.toLocaleTimeString();
var localeTime= lt.split(“:”);
var str=parseInt(localeTime[0]);
```

1. parseInt is returning NaN.
2. Try passing the value at localeTime[0] directly to parseInt() . It gives correct output which is numeric form of String passed to parseInt() .
3. Try localeTime[0]===Value at localeTime[0] . The output is false.

Comment: why don't you call the appropriate getters?

Comment: Also fails with `Number(localeTime[0]);`

Comment: I will do that , I just want to know why the parseInt() is not able to convert  string from the array to number.

Comment: Check out: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/863366/ie11-javascript-date-tolocaletimestring-length-incorrect  MS claims it is a feature.

Comment: Thanks everyone for quick reply .@JonSG let me go through the link you send .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `localeTime[0].length` you will see that it returns `4`.

```
localeTime[0] // "20"
localeTime[0].length // 4
x.charCodeAt(0) // 8206 -> ???
x.charCodeAt(1) // 50 -> "2" as expected
x.charCodeAt(2) // 48 -> "0" as expected
x.charCodeAt(3) // 8206 -> ???
```

For some reason in IE there are also two [additional characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) at start and end of token.

In order to make it work you would need to normalize string by removing all non-alphanumeric characters.

```
parseInt(localeTime[0].replace(/\W/, '')) // returns 20 as expected
```

Comment: Thanks Yariash for clarifying the concept .